# Error in tkinter GUI --invalid command name "2025099205632update_values" while executing

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am getting the error "invalid command name "2025099205632update_values"
while executing" in tkinter GUI code. I attached my code.I am using Spyder 4 and Python 3.6.

Please help me to solve this error.

This is my code. This display the random number on tkinter frame. at the interval of 1000 mill second.

main.py call the class object to start GUI
panel_meter.py create label frame and call the class "r_phase_parameter" in r_phase.py
In class r_phase_parameter global variable updated at 1000 ms. These are the random numbers.

"""
This is main.py file.
"""

```
from panel_meter import *

meter_Window = meter()
meter_Window.start()    


#########This is panel_meter.py file######################################


from tkinter import *
from r_phase import *

vol_r=100

class meter:
    def __init__(self):
        
        self.r_list = []       #This is not used 
      

        self.vol_r=vol_r
    
        self.col=0
    

        self.root=Tk()
        self.root.title('Meter')
       
        self.root.config(relief="sunken", borderwidth = 3,background="#FFFFF0")
         

        self.r_frame=LabelFrame(self.root,text="R Phase")   #,width=220,height=70
        self.r_frame.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
        self.r_frame.configure(foreground="red")
        self.r_frame.config(background="#FFFFF0")
        
        self.r_phase_read=r_phase_parameter(self.root,self.r_frame,self.vol_r,self.r_list) 
       
        
          
    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop()  

###########################r_phase.py#############################


from tkinter import *
import meter_globel
import random


class r_phase_parameter:
    
    def __init__(self,root,frame,r_vol,r_list):
        
        self.root=root
        self.frame=frame
      
       
        #self.frame.grid_propagate(0)
       
        self.l1=Label(self.frame,text='Voltage=' + str(meter_globel.r_globel_voltage)+'V',width=meter_globel.global_label_width)
        self.l1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
        self.l1.config(background="#FFFFF0")
        self.l1.after(meter_globel.update_time,self.update_values)
        
        self.l2=Label(self.frame,text='Current=' + str(meter_globel.r_globel_current)+'A',width=meter_globel.global_label_width)
        self.l2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
        self.l2.config(background="#FFFFF0")
        
        self.l3=Label(self.frame,text='Frequency=' + str(meter_globel.r_globel_frequency)+'Hz',width=meter_globel.global_label_width)
        self.l3.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)
        self.l3.config(background="#FFFFF0")
    
    def __del__(self):
        self.after_cancel(self.after_id)    
    
    
    def update_values(self):   
       
        meter_globel.r_globel_voltage=random.randrange(120,290) 
        meter_globel.r_globel_current=random.randrange(1,14)
        meter_globel.r_globel_frequency=random.randrange(1,55)
        
        
        if meter_globel.r_globel_voltage > 250:
            bgc_rv='red' 
        else :
            bgc_rv="Blue"
            
            
        if meter_globel.r_globel_current > 10:
            bgc_rc='red' 
        else :
            bgc_rc="Blue"    
            
            
        if meter_globel.r_globel_frequency > 50:
            bgc_rf='red' 
        else :
            bgc_rf="Blue"    
        
        
        self.l1.configure(text='Voltage=' + str(meter_globel.r_globel_voltage)+'V',fg=bgc_rv,width=meter_globel.global_label_width) 
        self.l2.configure(text='Current=' + str(meter_globel.r_globel_current)+'A',fg=bgc_rc,width=meter_globel.global_label_width)
        self.l3.configure(text='Frequency=' + str(meter_globel.r_globel_frequency)+'Hz',fg=bgc_rf,width=meter_globel.global_label_width)
      
        self.l1.after(meter_globel.update_time,self.update_values)    



##################This meter_global.py############################


r_globel_voltage=000

r_globel_current=00

r_globel_frequency=0


global_label_width= 12
update_time =1000    # This is in mill second
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting of the code. Your question is very hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must give your code clearer, I cannot reproduce your error, it works fine for me. However there were some attributeErrors but I fixed it.
I just brought up all together your code into single script.

```
from tkinter import * 
import random


#GLOBAL VARIABLES
vol_r=100
r_globel_voltage=000
r_globel_current=00
r_globel_frequency=0
global_label_width= 12 
update_time =1000 # This is in mill second

class r_phase_parameter:
    def __init__(self,root,frame,r_vol,r_list):
    
        self.root=root
        self.frame=frame
      
       
        #self.frame.grid_propagate(0)
       
        self.l1=Label(self.frame,text='Voltage=' + str(r_globel_voltage)+'V',width=global_label_width)
        self.l1.grid(row=0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10)
        self.l1.config(background="#FFFFF0")
        self.l1.after(update_time,self.update_values)
        
        self.l2=Label(self.frame,text='Current=' + str(r_globel_current)+'A',width=global_label_width)
        self.l2.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
        self.l2.config(background="#FFFFF0")
        
        self.l3=Label(self.frame,text='Frequency=' + str(r_globel_frequency)+'Hz',width=global_label_width)
        self.l3.grid(row=0,column=2,padx=10,pady=10)
        self.l3.config(background="#FFFFF0")

    def __del__(self):
        #################################
        #I have changed here, itself of of this class is not inherited any tkinter 
        # widget so it cannot use self.after_cancel
        #################################
        self.root.after_cancel(self.update_values)    
    
    
    def update_values(self):   
       
        r_globel_voltage=random.randrange(120,290) 
        r_globel_current=random.randrange(1,14)
        r_globel_frequency=random.randrange(1,55)
        
        
        if r_globel_voltage > 250:
            bgc_rv='red' 
        else :
            bgc_rv="Blue"
            
            
        if r_globel_current > 10:
            bgc_rc='red' 
        else :
            bgc_rc="Blue"    
            
            
        if r_globel_frequency > 50:
            bgc_rf='red' 
        else :
            bgc_rf="Blue"    
        
        
        self.l1.configure(text='Voltage=' + str(r_globel_voltage)+'V',fg=bgc_rv,width=global_label_width) 
        self.l2.configure(text='Current=' + str(r_globel_current)+'A',fg=bgc_rc,width=global_label_width)
        self.l3.configure(text='Frequency=' + str(r_globel_frequency)+'Hz',fg=bgc_rf,width=global_label_width)
      
        self.l1.after(update_time,self.update_values)


    
class meter: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.r_list = []       #This is not used 
  

        self.vol_r=vol_r
    
        self.col=0
    
    
        self.root=Tk()
        print("x")
        self.root.title('Meter')
       
        self.root.config(relief="sunken", borderwidth = 3,background="#FFFFF0")
         
    
        self.r_frame=LabelFrame(self.root,text="R Phase")   #,width=220,height=70
        self.r_frame.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10)
        self.r_frame.configure(foreground="red")
        self.r_frame.config(background="#FFFFF0")
        
        self.r_phase_read=r_phase_parameter(self.root,self.r_frame,self.vol_r,self.r_list) 
       
        
          
    def start(self):
        self.root.mainloop() 
        
        

meter_Window = meter() 
meter_Window.start()
```

However, when I run this code, it shows this window, no errors and it changes dynamically so I assume it works fine.

[image: Code output]

Comment: Thanks for your replay. When I run the code it work but still I getting this on console when I run code corrected by you. Please run code 2-3 times, you also see the same result. #######################################################################
x invalid command name "2305741651712update_values" while executing
"2305741651712update_values" ("after" script)
invalid command name "2305752030336update_values" while executing
"2305752030336update_values" ("after" script) ###################################################################